# d3 remove decimal values from chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

my d3 graph is putting in intermediary values between 0 and 1 at certain zoom levels  0 and 1 are actually part of my dataset so I can control the way they look in my yAxis parameters with the `tickFormat` accessor.

[image]

I don't want d3 to show the intermediary decimal values that it creates.

Since d3 is creating them out of thin air, I can't simply do `tickFormat(d3.format(", .0f")` as this only removes decimals from elements in my dataset.

How do I remove the fake values that d3 generates IF they are decimal values? At further out zoom levels I do want to see intermediary values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things that might help, from https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes:

```
# axis.ticks([arguments…])
```

Get or set the arguments that are passed to the underlying scale’s tick function. The specified *arguments* are passed to scale.ticks to compute the tick values. For quantitative scales, specify the desired tick count such as `axis.ticks(20)`.

**This hints at the number of ticks to use (although it doesn't always listen to you), but can decrease the clutter when you zoom in.**

or:

```
# axis.tickValues([values])
```

Get or set the explicit tick values. If the array *values* is specified, the values are used to generate ticks rather than using the scale's tick generator. If *values* is null, clears any previously-set explicit tick values, reverting back to the scale's tick generator. If *values* is not specified, returns the currently-set tick values, if any. For example, to generate ticks at specific values:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .tickValues([1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]);
```

**This sets the ticks explicitly, so you can set them to `[0, 1]`, although you will have to manually fix them when the user zooms out. Perhaps you can just compute integers in the zoomed range, etc.**

Comment: okay, doing `tickValues([0, 1, 2, 3]);` for a test worked to remove the decimal values in that one case seen in the screen shot, but can you elaborate on how I could use this method dynamically? I think I have an idea, I'll make a separate array from my data with just the yAxis in this data set

Comment: It depends how far out you're zooming. For example, you can just set ticks to integer values in the domain before drawing the scale. Or, you can call `ticks(2)` when you are zoomed to this size. If you post a fiddle of your data, I can make some more concrete suggestions, because I'm not sure exactly what you want to display for 0 and 1.

Comment: its okay I solved it, your suggestion guided me in the right direction.